# Making Akka Http Server Endpoints publicly Accesible

Tags: akka, akka-http

I have an Akka Http Server running on one machine, that i need to be accessible from another machine which is not on the same network. The akka server is bound using "0.0.0.0"

```
Http().bindAndHandle(route, "0.0.0.0", 9000)
```

And application.conf configuration used:

```
akka {
actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
    warn-about-java-serializer-usage = false
}
remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
        hostname = "0.0.0.0"
        port = 2557
        maximum-frame-size = 256000b
    }
}
```

This works if trying to access the endpoints from the machine they are running on but not on any other one.
I have tried connecting to the endpoints using the public and private ip address off the machine hosting the endpoints, with port 9000 and also 2557 but none of them work. Is there a way to be able to make the endpoints accessible from other machines?

Comment: By binding to `0.0.0.0` you are binding to all interfaces on the host. If it works if you're on the same machine but not from others then the first thing to check would be if you can actually get to that host from wherever you are. It sounds like it's networking routing issue.

Comment: @artur Thanks, this could well be the issue as they are both AWS Instances, If i am going to open the port for it to work, Is it port 9000 I open or port 2557? Or both?

Comment: If you want to open the HTTP service, then all you need is 9000.  2557 is to allow actors running on one akka instance to send messages to another (e.g. to form a cluster).